# reading/count character in the line?

Tags: python, count, character

I am trying to read / count the character on the file (which is located in line 2)

all the even line of the file looks similar to this:

---------------LL---NE--HVKTHTEEK---PF-ICTVCR-KS----------

here is my code so far but I got the error saying:

for character in len[(line2)]:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

```
 with open(filename) as f:
    for line, line2 in itertools.izip_longest(f, f, fillvalue=''):
        tokenizer=line.split()
        print line, line2
        print tokenizer[4]
        for character in len[(line2)]:
           print 't'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that `len` is a builtin function  (`len(mystring)` returns an integer which is the number of characters in the string).  You can't subscript it (i.e. using square brackets with it will result in the TypeError you've referenced in your question).  I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here, maybe you want:

```
 for character in line2:
     print character
```

or maybe you want:

```
 for i,character in enumerate(line2):
     print i,character
```

From the comments, I'm still having a hard time picking up what you want, but I think you might want something like this:

```
tokenizer = line.replace('-',' ').split()[4]
idx = line.index(tokenizer)
count = line[:idx].count('-')
```

Comment: I want to use that to count both alphabet excluding and including the '-'

Comment: @ChadD -- That's expected.  What are you trying to accomplish with your for loop?

Comment: There are multiple lines in the file so and the even line looks similar to the one i posted. so the number in tokenize[4] is the original position excluding '-' i want to know the new position of that, which sometime there might be '-' in front or in between the character

Comment: So, you want to know the index of the first non-`-` character on the line?

Comment: My question is "why?" - as in what's the result you require?

Comment: @JonClements i need to keep track of new position since tokenize[4] was old position.. and i need to count number of insertion'-' before tokenize[4]

Comment: so for example i have tokenizer[4] is 12, which is 'E' in the sequence and the sequence above.. i have to add all the '-' before 'E' and add the count of '-' to 12 which suppose to give me 32

Comment: I don't get what is idx and count do?

Comment: @ChadD -- How in the world is `tokenizer[4]` equal to 12?  As far as I can tell, `tokenizer[4]` isn't even defined.  However, let's assume that `tokenizer[4]` is indeed the integer 12, then to add the number of '-' to a preexising variable, you just do:  `variable += line[:tokenizer[4]].count('-')`  Because `count` simply counts the number of times a particular substring is in the whole string.

Comment: @ChadD -- doesn't work how?  did you initially set `variable = 0`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14649/discussion-between-chad-d-and-mgilson)

Answer (score 0):

`line2` is a string, and `len(line2)` is an integer (number of characters in `line2`).  Square brackets are used for indexing (or slicing) sequences, so for example you could get the first character of `line2` using `line2[0]`, or the last character using `line2[-1]`.

The `len` built-in function is not a sequence, which is why using square brackets after it causes the error you are seeing.

You can use a `for` loop to iteration, but you have to loop over something that is iterable.  You cannot iterate over an integer, so `for character in len(line2):` will fail as well.

Use one of the following methods instead:

```
# loop over each character in the string
for character in line2:
    ...

# loop over [0, 1, ..., len(line2)-1]
for i in range(len(line2)):
    ...

# combination of above methods, i will be the index of character in the string
for i, character in enumerate(line2):
    ...
```